Filter conversation detail query on media type Genesys Cloud .NET SDK
Im using Genesys cloud .NET SDK to fetch conversations using the "PostAnalyticsConversationsDetailsQuery". below is my code
var conversationsApi = new ConversationsApi();
 var startdate = DateString(currentTime.Subtract(fetchInterval));
 var enddate = DateString(currentTime);
 var matches = new List<PM.ConversationDetailQueryPredicate>();
 matches.AddRange(Divisions.Select(d => Matches(Dim.Divisionid, d)));
 var conversations = new List<PM.AnalyticsConversationWithoutAttributes>();
var pageNum = 1;
do
{
    var convs = conversationsApi.PostAnalyticsConversationsDetailsQuery(
        new PM.ConversationQuery(Interval: $"{startdate}/{enddate}",
            Paging: new PM.PagingSpec(100, pageNum++),
            ConversationFilters: new List<PM.ConversationDetailQueryFilter>()
            { Or(matches.ToArray()) }
            ));

    if (convs == null || convs.Conversations == null || convs.TotalHits == 0)
        break;

    conversations.AddRange(convs.Conversations
        ?.Where(y => y.ConversationEnd >= insertStartTime)
        ?.Where(z => true == z.Participants?
                                .Any(p => p.Purpose == PM.AnalyticsParticipantWithoutAttributes.PurposeEnum.Agent
                                       || p.Purpose == PM.AnalyticsParticipantWithoutAttributes.PurposeEnum.User)));
    
} while (true);

This is working fine however I'm getting all media types in the response. How can I filter only voice? I have tried adding the media type filter but it's not available in "ConversationDetailQueryPredicate". Is there a way to add this filter?
